# Linq to Entities Vs. Table Adapters (.Net Windows Forms)

Tags: .net, winforms, linq-to-entities, dataset, tableadapter

I'm starting on a small windows forms project that makes extensive use of editable grids.  I want to use Linq to Entities, but while it's trivial to bind a grid to the Linq query it's read-only.  I couldn't figure out a good way to have an editable grid that auto-updates the database.  (I hacked a work-around where I copy the data into a dataset for display/update and translate back... ugly!)

So for now I've decided to forget Linq to Entities and use the old table adapter/dataset method from 2.0.

Is there a compelling reason why I should use Linq to Entities instead?
Is there a way to do editable grids that I just missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:  use lambda expressions to filter the entity, then bind directly to the entity. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can just bind an entity collection returned by a query to an control and this will allow editing the bound entities. May be you should insert a `BindingSource` between collection and control, but that depends. If you call `SaveChanges()` on the object context the changes are persisted to the database. So data binding with the Entity Framework definitly works.

Comment: For some reason why I try that I get a read-only grid.  Perhaps it's the infragistics grid control I'm using?

Comment: I cannot tell if this is an issue with that control. Just try it with a DataGridView - this works without any tricks.

Comment: Thanks. I found I was binding to a query result, not the entity itself. Thus the read only. I'll give linq another shot.

Comment: I was able to successfully bind the entity to a grid with read/write.  However, the grid then fills in with all the data.  Linq allows queries, but the results are separate from the entity.  Binding to the query results is thus read-only.  An unfiltered grid isn't very usable. :-(